# What does the hexadecimal integer shown on print/repr in represent?

Tags: python

In an interactive session like the following one:

```
>>> f=open('test.txt','w')
>>> f
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'w' at 0x6e610>
```

What does **0x6e610** represent and what could I do with that hexadecimal number in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> f=open('test.txt')
>>> f
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x10047c938>
>>> hex(id(f))
'0x10047c938'
```

Have a look at [id in the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id):

*Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.*

Comment: So, it's not stricly related to address memory.

Comment: This means that there's no language specification that there should be a 'hard' correspondence to address memory (there is in the canonical CPython implementation, but this could be different in Jython, Cython, ...)

Comment: Note: Cython isn't really a different implementation, it's a language for making CPython C extensions. (The underlying message, that Jython and IronPython and PyPy could handle this differently is of course true.)

Comment: Good point about Cython. It's a little to late to edit my original comment, but thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

It's the ID of the object, which (in standard Python) is its address in memory.

You can also get it via the `id(obj)` function.

You can use IDs to tell whether two references refer to the same object - when you say `if x is y` in Python, you're comparing IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your response, x is y is a nice example.